# Экарирование всей строки в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, строки, format

В Python есть возможность экранирования всей строки с помощью f
Так

```
f'str/d/ning' # str/d/ning
```

Есть ли возможность в JS сделать так же?

Comment: Нет. Зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: я не хочу для каждого пути до файла экранировать каждый символ \ вручную или с помощью функции

Comment: Что-то вы делаете не так. Вообще не припомню что бы мне нужно было писать в явном виде длинные пути к файлам.

Comment: Так как я хочу в веб, то js мне необходим на данный момент, а для того, чтобы его учить, я прохожу разные олимпиады, используя этот язык. Плюс, он в разы быстрее питона, что мне сейчас необходимо

Comment: Это не отвечает на вопрос зачем внутри скриптов писать пути к файлам

Comment: Чтоюы тестовые данные не держать в js, а хранить в другом файле(допустим .txt). А если я буду и тестовые данные, и код хранить в одной директории, то будет каша

Comment: Впрочем, ответ на исходный  вопрос я уже написал.

Comment: Ну и, насколько я знаю, нода в винде понимает и обычные слеши, так что можно их писать